# How do you bind this type variable correctly?

Tags: haskell, type-variables

I've been digging out some old code (and frankly regretting some design decisions) but I realized I could never get the final function to compile and I don't really understand why. I've got ScopedTypeVariables on which normally solves problems like this for me.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, FlexibleContexts, RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable, DerivingStrategies, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

import Prelude hiding ((+), (*))
import Algebra
import Control.Lens.TH (makeLenses)
import Data.Semigroup (Semigroup, (<>))
import Data.Monoid (mempty, mappend)
import Data.Proxy (Proxy)
import Data.Function(on)
import qualified Data.IntMap as IM
import Control.Lens (IxValue, Index, Ixed(..), Traversal', Iso', view, review)

class (Ixed g) => Grid g where
    -- Stored x first, then y
    gridIso :: Iso' g (IM.IntMap (IM.IntMap (IxValue g)))
    storageVector :: (Index g) -> Vector2D Int

{-# INLINE gridIx #-}
gridIx :: forall g . (Grid g) => (Index g) -> Traversal' g (IxValue g)
gridIx v = gridIso . (ix x) . (ix y) 
   where (Vector2D x y) = storageVector v
```

instead I get this:

```
/mnt/c/Users/me/advent2018/src/Vector.hs:92:41: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Index g0’
                  with actual type ‘Index g’
      NB: ‘Index’ is a non-injective type family
      The type variable ‘g0’ is ambiguous
    • In the first argument of ‘storageVector’, namely ‘v’
      In the expression: storageVector v
      In a pattern binding: (Vector2D x y) = storageVector v
    • Relevant bindings include
        v :: Index g
          (bound at /mnt/c/Users/me/advent2018/src/Vector.hs:91:8)
        gridIx :: Index g -> Traversal' g (IxValue g)
          (bound at /mnt/c/Users/me/advent2018/src/Vector.hs:91:1)
```

Comment: Please post the definition of `Vector2D`.

Comment: I can't set up a project to verify this right now, but try `storageVector @g v` (you'll need to enable `TypeApplications` for this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening here is that in order to call `storageVector`, the compiler has to choose an instance of `Grid`, but it can't.

Normally a parameter type would be enough to pick the instance, but in this case the parameter is of type `Index g`, and `Index` is a non-injective type family (as the error message states), which means that you can go from `g` to `Index g`, but you can't go back. In other words, there is no way to figure out what `g` is just by knowing `Index g`.

So the compiler can't choose a `Grid` instance and rejects the program.

To help the compiler with this, you can explicitly specify the type that should be used for instance lookup. To do that, use the `TypeApplications` extension:

```
    where (Vector2D x y) = storageVector @g v
```

This will tell the compiler that it should use instance `Grid g` for the same `g`.

Note that for this to work it is crucial to declare `g` with a `forall` keyword, which you're already doing.